# select each customer's most recent purchase

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Microsoft Access 2010, I want to run a query that lists only the most recent purchase made by each and every customer.  Here is the SQL that I have so far:

```
SELECT ClientNumber, DateOfPurchase  
FROM ordersTable WHERE ClientNumber IN (  
SELECT MAX(DateOfPurchase)  
FROM ordersTable  
GROUP BY ClientNumber  
);
```

The problem is that this query is not returning any data, despite their being relevant data in ordersTable.  How do I alter the code above so that it works?

Comment: Your inner query returns a list of dates, and then your outer query is trying to find orders that have client numbers matching those dates. Since dates and client numbers won't ever match, the outer query won't return any data.

Comment: Run the inner query, then see what 'in' is supposed to do and there's your problem ;-) @hamza kubba beat me to it :P

Comment: Adding sample data in a tabular format and your expected output too would help better understand the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you can solve this by joining the table to itself:

```
SELECT o.ClientNumber, o.DateOfPurchase  
FROM ordersTable o JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(DateOfPurchase) as MaxDateOfPurchase, ClientNumber
    FROM ordersTable  
    GROUP BY ClientNumber  
) t ON o.ClientNumber = t.ClientNumber AND o.DateOfPurchase = t.MaxDateOfPurchase
```

With that said, if you're not selecting any other fields, the subquery will work by itself:

```
SELECT MAX(DateOfPurchase) as MaxDateOfPurchase, ClientNumber
FROM ordersTable  
GROUP BY ClientNumber
```

*Edit, given you're using MS Access, you will perhaps need the keyword `AS` when aliasing a column.*

Comment: Your subqueries are missing their `AS`es in the `SELECT` clauses.

Comment: @sgeddes can be problem in rare situation when user have 2 orders made with the same DateOfPurchase

Comment: `AS` generally isn't needed with most `RDBMS` to alias a field or table.  With that said, perhaps it is with `MS Access` (been a while since I used that one!).

Comment: @IlyaBursov -- good point -- would need to know more information about the table schema and desired results :)

Answer (score -1):

"AS" is not generally needed, but in a long piece of code that other people may need to look at later it can be REALLY helpful! As can choosing informative alias names.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33038978)